# Windows Server 2008 Send an email on reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I want to send an email when a Windows Server reboots or shutdown unexpectedly.

I was reading that one way to achieve that is look for event id 6008 on System's log, and then send the alert.

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I want to use a PowerShell script if possible.

Comment: It is simple enough to send an email on system start. However, an unexpected shutdown implies you are monitoring the system externally and looking for some sort of heartbeat (like a ping response). Because if the system itself is dead, there will be no life capable of sending the notification. Do you have a system like that in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a scheduled task that runs at startup to run a script like this:

```
$lastBootTime = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select lastbootuptime
$lastBootTime = $lastBootTime.lastbootuptime

$events = Get-EventLog -LogName System -After $lastBootTime | where {$_.eventId -eq 6008}

if ($events -ne $null) {
    Send-MailMessage -From server@example.com -Subject "Unexpected shutdown detected on server" -To admin@example.com
}
```